# RNeoj: RStudio cannot connect to neo4j Database error 503 indicated

Tags: r, neo4j, rstudio, r-neo4j

**How can I get RStudio to connect to Neo4j database?**

**Problem:**

The following error is indicated when I attempt
to connect to neo4j database via RStudio using **startGraph** :

**Error:** 
     Server error: (**503**) Service Unavailable

```
#load library
library(RNeo4j)

#connect to graphdb
graph = startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
```

(dbm authenthication is disabled  [dbms.security.auth_enabled=false])
(Also tried with authentication enabled (by passing db username and password to startGraph), however the same error was indicated)

```
graph = startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data", 
         username="xxxx", password="xxxx")
```

**Initial Setup Check:**

Confirmed successful installation and operation of Neo4j.

```
1.Database is started and running successfully via neo4j (3.0.1) console

2.Confirmed able to connect successfully via Chrome Browser

3.Confirmed able to create graph and conduct queries via Chrome Browser interface.
```

**Environment Info**

```
    proxy is configured on system
    RNeo4j version 1.6.4
    RStudio V. 0.99.892
    R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

**Additional Details**

I don't have any issues with proxy and RStudio creating and running Shiny Apps or installing any R packages on system.

I performed a netstat to check connections on localhost ports only applications connected are Neo4j and Web Browsers, not RStudio. (Is it normal to have so many connections open at one time?)

```
d:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc>netstat -a -o -n  |grep :7474
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       15528
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         127.0.0.1:50884        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         127.0.0.1:50885        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         127.0.0.1:50886        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         127.0.0.1:50888        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         127.0.0.1:50889        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         127.0.0.1:50898        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         127.0.0.1:50899        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         127.0.0.1:50913        ESTABLISHED     15528
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         127.0.0.1:50914        ESTABLISHED     15528
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         127.0.0.1:50915        ESTABLISHED     15528
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         127.0.0.1:50916        ESTABLISHED     15528
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         127.0.0.1:50917        ESTABLISHED     15528
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         127.0.0.1:50918        ESTABLISHED     15528
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50887        127.0.0.1:7474         TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50900        127.0.0.1:7474         TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50901        127.0.0.1:7474         TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50902        127.0.0.1:7474         TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50913        127.0.0.1:7474         ESTABLISHED     12356
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50914        127.0.0.1:7474         ESTABLISHED     12356
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50915        127.0.0.1:7474         ESTABLISHED     12356
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50916        127.0.0.1:7474         ESTABLISHED     12356
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50917        127.0.0.1:7474         ESTABLISHED     12356
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50918        127.0.0.1:7474         ESTABLISHED     12356
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully execute startGraph by bypassing the proxy for localhost.

Steps

1.I first troubleshooted the issue using curl outside at a windows command prompt using the [noproxy] option to successful conclusion (verified this works correctly):

`curl -v --noproxy localhost, http://localhost:7474/db/data/`

2.Then at the RStudio console I set my httr configuration (since it is same underlying curl interface) to use [noproxy] option  by doing the following:

```
rstudio_console>set_config(config(noproxy = "localhost"))  #set noproxy option

rstudio_console>set_config(config(verbose()))      #set verbose to view http messages
```

3.Then execute startGraph with no options:

`rstudio_console>> graph = startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data")`

4.Voila Success:

```
rstudio_console> graph 

< Graph > 

$version
[1] "3.0.1"
```

Comment: Reference issue reported on **Github** for **additional details:**  [rneo4j_github](https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j/issues/54)